# Spring security remember me overriding default SQL of persistent_logins table

Tags: spring-security, token, persistent, remember-me

I have successfully implemented Remember Me functionality in my application.

Only I want to alter is that i do not want to use default table name persistent_logins at all.
So I want to update default sql in **JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl**.

**JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl** not providing any setter or getter method to override default persistent_logins table creation,record select, update queries.

Is there any easy way to use customized table instead of persistent_login table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not as it stands. You would have to implement `PersistentTokenRepository` yourself. It is quite a simple interface.